# Errores al compilar mi aplicación de Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, gradle

Buen día comunidad, se me presento un problema al modificar el valor del: "minSDK" en Android Studio, y lo que sucedió fue que obtuve dos errores al momento de ejecutar la aplicación.

Error 1: **Manifest file does not exist**

Error 2: **compileSDKVersion is not especified. Please add it to build.gradle**

Buscando información y soluciones en la red, no pude encontrar algo que me ayude a entender a que se deben y como solucionarlo adecuadamente, además de saber como modificar los valores que se encuentran en el "gradle". Es por eso que hago esta publicación.

**build.gradle(:app)**

```
plugins {
        id 'com.android.application'
    }
    
    android {
        compileSdk 31
    
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.qr"
            minSdk 26
            targetSdk 31
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
    
            testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
    
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }
        compileSdkVersion 31
        buildToolsVersion '31.0.0'
    }
```

**build.gradle("Nombre de la app")**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android-library'
```

**Imagenes**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Actualización**
Cuando baje el valor de: "minSDK", lo baje por la siguiente línea de código

```
MatrixToImageWriter.writeToPath(bitMatrix, "png", file.toPath());
```

El error que obtenia de esa líena era este:
**Call requires API level 26 (current min is 24): `java.io.File#toPath`**

Answer (score 1):

Aunque los errores indican que no existe el archivo `AndroidManifest.xml`, el problema se debe seguramente a la configuraciòn de tu proyecto, especificamente en el archivo `build.gradle`.

El error puede ser lo que indica el segundo error

> compileSDKVersion is not specified

en archivo `app/build.gradle`, en lugar de `compileSdk` usa `compileSdkVersion`, lo mismo para `minSdk` y `targetSdk`, realiza el siguiente cambio:

```
...
android {
    compileSdkVersion 31 //*

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.qr"
        minSdkVersion 26 //*
        targetSdkVersion 31 //*
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        ...
```

Comment: Buen día Jorge, hare los cambios que mencionas para ver que es lo que sucede y comentarte.

Comment: Hice los cambios que me indicaste y no aún persisten los mismos problemas. ¿Puede ser algo más? o el proyecto se perdió.

Comment: Limpia y crea el proyecto nuevamente